# Why is my Display Controller Intel when I have nvidia graphics card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display

When I run lspci command i get this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 OEM] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Now I am no expert at Linux drivers and how their graphics stuff works, but I know in Windows I could display my integrated Intel graphics via Device Manager as to ensure my computer was pushing everything thru my Nvidia GTX 660 card.

So my questions is, why is my Display Controller Intel when I have an Nvidia card? Or is this just the way it is supposed to be, because I have been running a couple of games that have nice graphics at maxed settings and I doubt the Intel could keep up with that...but I just can't figure out why it says Intel under Display Controller.

Any feedback would be helpful, and I tried finding the answer to this but I am thinking it is such a simple answer that no one has ever asked before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the issue, the GTX 660 cards are just having fickle support currently for anything outside of 12.04LTS. Furthermore, I thought that "display adapter" was what my OS was using for graphics, but seeing as how I am plugged directly into my graphics card, and it is clearly displayed as "VGA Controller", that is what's being used.

Problem: Display adapter & VGA Controller showing 2 different sources.
Answer: running `lspci | grep VGA` clearly shows the card being utilized.

Recommend anyone with 600 series cards sticking with 12LTS for better support.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean? The nVidia card is right there. It's a VGA compatible controller:

```
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
0:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 OEM] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

You need to install the drivers, however, to unlock the full power. You can open the Dash and search for `Proprietary Drivers` to find the install wizard.

Intel devices identify themselves as a `Display Controller`, while nVidia cards identify themselves as a `VGA compatible controller`. Same thing. They are synonyms. Your monitor is probably plugged into the Intel card though, making that the device that actually controls the display.

**This is normal and expected behavior.**

Comment: What I am asking is why does this say Intel:
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Why isnt the display controller my nvidia graphics card?

Comment: @MikeUresti Better?